# Vim bind ctrl arrow key not working on osx

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, iterm2

I know they have many topics about that, but i no one of them works.

My configuration worked before to switch between split window, but my session has been re-init and i lost my osx config and it's not working anymore.

In my `.vimrc` i have:

```
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>^[A <Nop>
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>^[B <Nop>
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>^[D <Nop>
nnoremap <silent> <ESC>^[C <Nop>

nnoremap <silent> <C-Right> <c-w>l
nnoremap <silent> <C-Left> <c-w>h
nnoremap <silent> <C-Up> <c-w>k
nnoremap <silent> <C-Down> <c-w>j
```

On `iTerm` i set my terminal as `Terminal App default` (i tried with `xterm default` too)

In the system preference, i disable the mission control keys with `ctrl + arrow key` in System preference.

with `sed -n l` i have

LEFT: `^[[D` | CTRL + LEFT:  `^[[5D`

Comment: See the faq [here](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4) and [here](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5)

Comment: So `nnoremap <silent> <esc>[5D <c-w>h` should work !

Comment: Awesome @ChristianBrabandt ! Thank you i didn't know the ctr+k ctrl+v tips !! i fix the ctrl left and right, but the problem is `^-k  ^ <up> ` print me `<Up>` instead of `<C-Up>` any idea ?